# Alloy model - how to display cycle in visualization of graph?

Tags: graph, cycle, alloy

We have an Alloy model intended to find possible deadlocks in a system. It is set up such that when a counterexample is found, that implies the system being modeling may have a deadlock, i.e. a circular dependency between nodes in the graph. The problem is the visual model of the graph is so complicated, it's nearly impossible to find the cycle representing the deadlock. If there were a way to highlight the cycle, or at least perhaps highlight arcs in the graph that are directed "up" rather than "down" this would help us visualize things better (since in the model we have, a deadlock-free system has all arcs directed in a downward direction). Is there a way to highlight or selectively plot nodes and arcs that create the counterexample?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first thing that comes to my mind is that when Alloy shows an instance of a predicate, the various arguments to the predicate can be styled specially.  So you might try (1) defining a predicate that is the inverse of your assertion, i.e. one that holds when a deadlock is present and which assigns a named role to the nodes in the cycle, and (2) setting the style to display those nodes in a distinct color or shape.  You may be able to hide everything that's *not* in the cycle, or gray it out.

Comment: Thanks very much for your help. We implemented something along the lines of what you suggested and it is nicely displaying just the nodes in the cycle when Alloy detects a deadlock cycle.

Comment: If your question has been answered satisfactorily, Stack Overflow suggests you should 'accept' that answer by clicking the check box you will see next to each answer to a question you have asked.  That way, searches can distinguish successfully between answered and unanswered questions.

Comment: Thanks - I clicked the "check" box.